# how to preview the adjacency list tree by using for loops (Non-recursive solution)

Tags: php, mysql, tree, adjacency-list

I store a tree in MySQL database by using the adjacency list method

when I want to preview the tree, PHP retrieves the whole tree from the database and preview it using recursion.

But iterations is better than recursion in performance, so I want to populate the tree using the for loops to achieve better performance.

I do not want to use any MySQL functions or methods or triggers, I just want to populate the tree by using iterations (for loops)

Comment: Why are iterations better for performance?

Comment: Posting some code to show what you mean would be helpful

Comment: if you know the exact dimensions of the tree you can use for loops but if the dimensions of the tree change then you will have to use recursion in order to get the whole tree.

Comment: Why are iterations better for performance? http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

most languages aren't designed for recursive functions. For each node, the function starts another instance of itself. So, for a tree with four levels, you'll be running four instances of the function at the same time. As each function occupies a slice of memory and takes some time to initiate, recursion is very slow when applied to large trees.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this old unanswered question, while searching for a link to aide in answering a similar question on IRC.

This is a rough example showing how to build a list of paths from an adjacency list, it requires the data to be sorted by the 'parent' then 'id', this could easily be translated to an SQL `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY parent, id` clause:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'parent' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent' => 2], 
    ['id' => 4, 'parent' => 3], 
    ['id' => 5, 'parent' => 0],
    ['id' => 6, 'parent' => 5],
    ['id' => 7, 'parent' => 5], 
    ['id' => 8, 'parent' => 7],
    ['id' => 9, 'parent' => 8],
    ['id' => 10, 'parent' => 5],
    ['id' => 11, 'parent' => 0],
    ['id' => 12, 'parent' => 5],
    ['id' => 13, 'parent' => 5],
    ['id' => 14, 'parent' => 11],
    ['id' => 15, 'parent' => 13],
    ['id' => 16, 'parent' => 1],
    ['id' => 17, 'parent' => 15],
];

usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return $a['parent'] - $b['parent']?: $a['id'] - $b['id']; });

$paths = [];
foreach($arr as $current) {
    if($current['parent'] > 0) {
        $paths[ $current['id'] ] = array_merge($paths[ $current['parent'] ], [ $current['parent'] ]);
    } else {
        $paths[ $current['id'] ] = [];
    }
}

ksort($paths);
foreach($paths as $k => $v) {
    printf("%s => %s\n", $k, implode('/', array_merge($v, [ $k ])));
}
```

Output:

```
1 => 1
2 => 1/2
3 => 1/2/3
4 => 1/2/3/4
5 => 5
6 => 5/6
7 => 5/7
8 => 5/7/8
9 => 5/7/8/9
10 => 5/10
11 => 11
12 => 5/12
13 => 5/13
14 => 11/14
15 => 5/13/15
16 => 1/16
17 => 5/13/15/17
```